# (Google cloud platform) Gcp portforwarding not working

Tags: networking, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am trying to forward the port tcp 32400

I  doing this for a windows server 2012 vm running plex media server the vm is hosted on Google cloud platform.

Answer (score 0):

install “plex server”

set port in “plex server / web admin / server / remote access / port : 32400”

set that port in “gcp > vpc > firewall > ingress”  32400 for all/ specific ip

Please refer https://forums.plex.tv/t/q-how-to-activate-remote-access-plex-media-server-pms-in-google-cloud-platform-gcp/275064/5

Comment: How much ram does a desktop Linux distro really need (including plex)

Comment: Plex Media Server Requirements- https://support.plex.tv/articles/200375666-plex-media-server-requirements/

Comment: @maximilianpult  please check above link of system requirements. its minimum requirements, depends on uses can increase